# Passing parameters from another form to form with ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Hello I have got `ReportViewer` in my `Form2` and I got some `textboxes` in `Form1` and on `button_click` event in Form1 I open form2 and pass these strings:

```
 string klient_name = txt_name.Text;
        string klient_address2 = txt_adress2.Text;
        string klient_address = txt_adress.Text;
        voucher_sestava a = new voucher_sestava();
        a.k_name = klient_name;
        a.k_address2 = klient_address2;
        a.k_address = klient_address;
        a.Show();
```

On `Form2` I got following code:

```
public string k_name { get; set; }
    public string k_address2 { get; set; }
    public string k_address { get; set; }

private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("name",k_name);
        ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("address",k_address);
        ReportParameter p3 = new ReportParameter("address2", k_address2);


        this.firmaTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataset_voucher.firma);
        this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2, p3 }); 
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

When I try to write in `Expression` of reportviewer's textbox like this:

```
=Parameters!name.Value
```

I got following error:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox14’ refers to a
>   non-existing report parameter ‘name’. Letters in the names of
>   parameters must use the correct case.

May someone please help me fixing this? Thanks so much.

Comment: `ReportViewer` doesn't have any `TextBox` for you to write any expression. In fact that's the design surface of the `Local Report` or another kind of report which supports design time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem was that I haven't created the `Report Parameters` in the `Report.rdlc` file.

It can be done by going to `Report Data` - right click `Parameters` - `Add Parameters`.

Fill the name of parameter that must be same as is parsed:

p3 = new ReportParameter("address", textBox1.Text);

You can allow `null value` and `blank value` if needed. (I used in this case`

The final code should look like this:

```
ReportParameter[] parameter = new ReportParameter[3]; // 3 indicates number of total parameters passed
parameter[0] = new ReportParameter("rp_name", textBox1.Text);
parameter[1] = new ReportParameter("rp_surname", textBox3.Text);
parameter[2] = new ReportParameter("rp_address",textBox2.Text;

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score -1):

Parameters are case sensitive.  Change the value of Textbox14 to correct case. Either upper or lower.

Comment: does it add anything to the answer?